# is it possible to declare this type for an external lib in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I've got an external library that I want to add flow type definitions for. However one issue I have is that the lib uses a callback system that depends on `this` value. Something like this:

```
function callback() {
  this.doSth();
}
extlib(callback);
```

Since it's an external library, flow doesn't know the context of the call, and as such `this.doSth()` doesn't get checked whether it exists and what if any parameters it can be called with.
Typescript allows defining extlib like this:

```
type Callback = (this: ThisType) => void;
declare extlib(cb: Callback);
```

which as far as I'm aware is not supported by flow.

Is there any way of annotating that, other than something like this:

```
function callback() {
  let context: ThisType = this;
  context.doSth();
}
```

While it works, It's rather ugly as it moves typing responsibility from the lib do the developer.

Comment: I don't believe it's currently possible. See this github issue that's still open: 
[Issue 452](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/452).  It looks like someone did open a PR but it hasn't been approved yet.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know of that issue, I was just hoping there might be some trick to bypass that. It's a shame there isn't then